# Dropdown undefined javascript form validation error

Tags: javascript, forms

I have the following sample of html code:

```
<form id="registration" action="process.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
    <label for="range_date" class="form">Select Range Date</a></label>
    <select name="range_date">
        <option value="" style="display:none;"></option>
        <option value="June 27th 2014 6:00pm">June 27th 2014 6:00pm</option>
        <option value="June 27th 2014 8:00pm">June 27th 2014 8:00pm</option>
    </select>
</form >
```

And the following sample js code:

```
if (document.forms["registration"]["range_date"] != 'undefined') 
{
    var range_date=document.forms["registration"]["range_date"].value;
    if (range_date==null || range_date=="")
    {  
        alert("Please select a Range Date");
        return false;
    }  
}
```

I get an error in firebug stating: "document.forms.registration.range_date is undefined" but I don't expect it to reach the inside of the if statement. Any thoughts?

Comment: That isn't a combobox; it's a dropdown.

Comment: You're correct. I updated it. Thanks

Comment: Try `document.forms["registration"]["range_date"] != null && document.forms["registration"]["range_date"] != undefined`

Comment: Your problem does not originate from the sample you provided, eventhough it's not 100% correct. It runs: http://jsfiddle.net/Vznaw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `'undefined' != undefined`.

Just use a truthy check

```
if (document.forms["registration"]["range_date"]) {
```

or drop the quotes

```
if (document.forms["registration"]["range_date"]===undefined) {
```